# Zebra_Session $_SESSION['user'] passing variable

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I am using Zebra Session as a Session wrapper in an attempt to make my site more secure.

The issue I'm having is:

A user inputs login details, these are then passed to login-function.php. The details are checked against a database (using PHP's built in functions and prepared statements).

If the login is successfull, the user is redirected to their profile page and a variable is stored called $_SESSION['user'] - containing their email address is recorded to use in queries at a later date (Secure?)

Profile-function.php is required in the page like so: 
"require('path to/profile-function.php');

and uses "if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){" to see if the Session variable is set, if so, echo the rest of the contents.

A session is started on each page like so:

```
$link = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "username", "password", "table");

if($link->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
}

$secint = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(12));

require('pathto/Zebra_Session.php');
$session = new Zebra_Session($link, $secint);
```

at the very top after the opening PHP tags.

The variable is being recorded as I can pass it via the url in the login-function.php script.

Do I need to pass the variable using $_POST between pages, as my understanding is Zebra_Session records session data to the database, however there is no data being recorded in the BLOB field on my database.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what's wrong with your setup.

### 1. make sure the table exists.

```
 $ mysql --table -e 'DESCRIBE session_data;' 
 +----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
 +----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | session_id     | varchar(32) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
 | hash           | varchar(32) | NO   |     |         |       |
 | session_data   | blob        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | session_expire | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |       |
 +----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

2. Use a constant string for the key-phrase

   $secint = 'óÆÐ0¬ßyÚmø¼P±¼ÚÎ}m²WÑ`ä^^N¦Б]-¤íó­¼0[ã']Àâ¿2..Yñ¥ÅúøL';

Every time some session data is stored and signed, one usually wants to get the data back. If you use a different key-phrase each time, you will never be able to read or verify the stored hash.